# Copying and assigning classes with pointers as member variables

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm working on a project in C++ where I have defined a class that besides some data stores an array of pointers to these data. Simplified, it would look like this:

```
class myclass{  
    std::array<int,N1> A;
    std::array<int,N2> B;
    std::array<int,N3> C;
    std::array<int*,Np> Pt;
    myclass(...) {...};
    // other data and member functions
}
```

So, `Pt` is an array of pointers that point to the integer elements in `A, B` or `C`. I do not know to which of the integer-arrays and to which element therein a pointer in `Pt` points to (this changes continuously during runtime) and the class uses these pointers to administrate the data. Now I want to copy and assign objects of this class:

```
myclass X(...);
myclass Y(...); 
...
Y=X;
```

Now the porblem is, of course, that the pointers in `Y.Pt` still point to the int-arrays in `X` because the addresses stored in the pointers are not shifted when copying. In order to solve this and to make the pointers in `Y.Pt` point to the corresponding elements in `Y` as they should, I had the idea to use pointer arithmetic to explicitly shift the addresses stored in `Y.Pt` about the number of integer-sizes in memory that lie between `X` and `Y` which I find by calculating for example the difference between the addresses of Y.A[0] and X.A[0] (which I assume to be the same as the difference between the first elements in Y.B and X.B or in Y.C and X.C):

```
size_t shift = &Y.A[0]-&X.A[0];
for (size_t i=0; i<Np; ++i)
    {Y.Pt[i] += shift;}
```

So, I tried this and it seems to work fine, however, is this really save, even when I run my program on a different machine with different compiler optimizations? It should work if the distance in memory between `Y.A` and `X.A` is always the same as the distance between `Y.B` and `X.B` and between `Y.C` and `X.C`. Can I always rely on that? Can I imagine copying and assignment as a translation of a copied version of the entire object to a new location in memory? Or could it happen that e.g. `X.A` is stored directly next to `Y.A` and identically for `B` and `C` for reasons of optimization? 
Another thing is that `int` occupies more than 1 byte (usually 4 bytes). What happens if the distance in memory between `X.A` and `Y.A` is not a multiple of 4 bytes because maybe some other data types are stored in between? Should I better cast the integer pointers `&X.A[0]` and `&Y.A[0]` to byte pointers like `char*` and calculate `shift` from those as the number of bytes and use this to perform the shift?:

```
size_t shift = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Y.A[0])-reinterpret_cast<char*>(&X.A[0]);
for (size_t i=0; i<Np; ++i)
{
    Y.Pt[i] = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Y.Pt[i]) + shift);
}
```

Would that be better? Is there some better or standard solution to this kind of problem? Thanks very much for help!

Comment: The layout of the same class is identical for all these instances.But I think that `&Y.A[0]-&X.A[0]` is UB (even if it should work in practice).

Comment: I think that to not be UB, you have to check to which `array` the pointer belong (and so offset from the start of this array), and then apply the corresponding offset from the equivalent array.

Comment: If you can, avoid using these int pointers. They don't help (they don't save any memory, since a pointer takes the same amount of space as an int), and they make this part tricky. Can you, instead, keep track of which array, and which index they point to?